# How to make Silverlight TextBox.TextChanged event fire synchronously?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, textbox, textchanged

**Platform:** Silverlight 4 / .NET 4

**Description:**

I have a `ComboBox`, a `Textbox` and a `NumericUpDown`.

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <ComboBox SelectionChanged="cmbChanged" Margin="3">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="A" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="B" />
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt" TextChanged="txtChanged" Margin="3"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chk" Checked="chkChecked" Unchecked="chkChecked" Content="Check box" Margin="3"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="lst" Height="100" Margin="3"/>
</StackPanel>
```

A list is for debugging purposes.

**Repro:**

Note that there are event handlers for `TextBox.TextChanged`, `CheckBox.Checked`, `CheckBox.Unchecked` and `ComboBox.SelectionChanged`.

Here are the handlers:

```
private void cmbChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lst.Items.Clear();
    txt.Text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex.ToString();
    chk.IsChecked = !chk.IsChecked;
}

private void txtChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lst.Items.Add("Text Changed");
}

private void chkChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool? chk = (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked;
    lst.Items.Add("CheckBox Changed to " + chk);
}
```

**Problem:**

In the combobox's event handler, I set the text in the textbox **BEFORE** setting the check state of the checkbox. However, if you take a look at the picture below, you will see that the event handler for the `CheckBox.Checked` gets called before `TextBox.TextChanged`.

[image: TextBox.TextChanged occurs asynchronously]

The problem is obviously in the asynchronous execution of the TextBox.TextChanged event, [as stated in the MSDN definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc190844%28v=VS.95%29.aspx):

> The TextChanged event is asynchronous. The event cannot be canceled.

I really **need these event handlers to execute exactly in the order** they are changed.

**Question:**
Is there any simple way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it might be better to call your piece of business logic directly, instead of relying on the event handlers. You can always remove and add the EventHandler in case you don't want to hit that trigger in your particular situation:

```
//Remove event handlers:
CheckBox.Checked -= chkChecked;
TextBox.TextChanged -= txtChanged;

//Call your business stuff here

//You can also 'safely' set values on your textbox and 
//checkbox since they wont trigger events now.

//Re-add event handlers, so they react on user input again:
CheckBox.Checked += chkChecked;
TextBox.TextChanged += txtChanged;
```

Comment: This doesn't make the event handler occur synchronously, but it solves my problem. I believe the complications would occur if there are multiple event handlers associated with the event. I'd have to unsubscribe them all, and then subscribe them again after the business logic. I find this to pollute the code, but without better solution, I will go with this.

Comment: How are you going to get to the call for the business logic? What would be the trigger?

Comment: The problem I was facing is that the combobox would set the textboxes, and if textbox values were to be changed - the combobox would have to select a predefined value. That's circular event handling. ComboBox would cause TextBox.TextChanged which would in turn cause ComboBox.SelectionChanged - and the recursion would either cause Stack overflow, or perform some undesired behavior. Thus the "logic" in this case is simply setting the values of the textbox while preventing the textbox from handling its TextChanged events.

Comment: Perhaps its also better to use data bindings and not rely on these events too much, esp since their behavior might not always be what you expect or want. Also, it might be prone to change in the future versions of the .NET framework, so its much nicer to use your own events on your viewmodel perhaps?

Comment: @Kornelije Petak : Sorry to say it but it sounds as though you've got a dodgy architecture, if you update your textbox then that should surely update your model, not the controls on the page, and that should cause the bound controls to change as appropriate. As Arcturus mentioned, relying on events for this isn't the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Silverlight guy so these are suggestions:

Use the KeyDown/KeyUp events to capture changes to your text box.
Use the FocusManager to manage synchronous GotFocus/LostFocus events and check for changes there.

Comment: KeyDown/KeyUp events won't detect changes made from mouse right-click / copy-paste, so this can't be used. I think the solution suggested is more of a hack than a correct way to handle the problem. But I am grateful for your reply anyway.

Comment: My question to you would be why do you need to have this specific order? What are you trying to achieve? One could argue that any attempt to subvert the normal operation of the environment is a "hack" ;)

Comment: Yup, I would say that the decision to make the TextChanged event asynchronous (even for Silverlight) while leaving almost all other events synchronous is a hack in itself. :) I'd like to hear SL designers on the subject... I can't explain why I need them in order - partly because I've posted only a repro for the problem, while my solution is much more complex, and partly because the solution with unsubscribing and subscribing circumvents the problem itself. Read the comment on the question for more details and the actual problem.